# Using a web service with cascading drop downs

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Below is my code -

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" />
 <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cddCategory" runat="server" ServicePath="~\Categories.asmx"
 ServiceMethod="GetCategories" TargetControlID="ddlCategories" Category="Category"
 PromptText="Please select a category" LoadingText="[Loading categories...]" />
 <br />
```

In my Page_Load function I have

```
{
        ddlCategories.DataBind();
}
```

and my GetCategories Method is

```
    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetCategories(
      string knownCategoryValues,
      string category)
    {
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> l = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        l.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue("International", "1"));
        l.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue("Electronic Bike Repairs & Supplies", "2"));
        l.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue("Premier Sport, Inc.", "3"));
        return l.ToArray();
    }
```

But when the page is loaded, the GetCategories function is never called. And my ddlCategories drop down has these items in the list -
Please select a category
[Method Error 400]

Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the CascadingDropDown [sample](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) and your code, I think you may have the properties set slightly wrong. Your CascadingDropDown's `TargetControlId` is currently ddlCategories, however I think this value should be set to the `ParentControlId` property instead, and you need *another* DropDownList which becomes the target control of the extender e.g.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" /><br/>
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlSubcategories" runat="server" />
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cddCategory" TargetControlID="ddlSubcategories" ParentControlId="ddlCategories" runat="server" ServicePath="~\Categories.asmx" 
ServiceMethod="GetCategories" Category="Category"  
PromptText="Please select a category" LoadingText="[Loading categories...]" />
```

Comment: Phil, Here is what TargetControlId is defined as - •TargetControlID - The ID of the DropDownList to populate. Other ideas?

Comment: @duckmike What's your understanding of what CascadingDropDown does? Mine is that you have two or more dropdown lists where the CascadingDropDown extender is applied to the second (and subsequent) dropdowns, so that when you select an item in the first dropdown, the extender intercepts the selection and filters the list in the next dropdown to whatever set of values is appropriate. Hence, you need two dropdownlists where the extender is applied to the second one.